# SQL Query to retrieve co-related values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below

```
Id     Parent_id      Dept_id
666      777           D101
555      666           D201
444      555           D301
333      444           D401
```

I know only the value 'D401'. Using this, I need to find all its co-related id and parent_id. Can anyone help me out to construct a query to fetch the values from the table.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332

Comment: So which rows to you want to be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name said,you can use CONNECT BY to get Hierarchical Query in oracle.If you want to get all related Id,you can try this：

```
SELECT Id FROM tablename
START WITH Dept_id='D401'
CONNECT BY Id=prior Parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks Angus.. It was quiet simple and clear. I got the result which I have expected!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a recursive cte:

```
with recursive(id,p,d)as
(
  select Id,Parent_id,Dept_id
  from tbl where Dept_id='D401' --put the dept id here
  union all
  select t.Id,t.Parent_id,t.Dept_id
  from tbl t join recursive r
  on t.id=r.p
)

select * from recursive
```

here is the [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c99ff/2)

**EDIT:** thanks to [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), you can use the `connect by` also, [here is the demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c99ff/3) provided by him.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes of course, your comments are always usefull

Comment: Note that the use of  `recursive` is a bit dangerous because it is a reserved word - and theoretically it is required by the SQL standard for a recursive cte: `with recursive cte_name (..) as ( ...)` but Oracle ignored that part of the standard (other DBMS do not)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are 100% right. I edited the answer and mentioned your solution also, please if you have a problem with mentioning or any other hint or points, edit the answer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not very clear. As per my understanding you can simply use;

```
SELECT id,parent_id
FROM tablename
WHERE dept_id = 
    (SELECT dept_id 
     FROM deptmaster_tablename 
     WHERE dept_name ='marketing')
```